# Changing field fill of max value in column groups on SSRS 2014

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2014

I have a table in SSRS that has both row and column groups.

For each row group [Cat], I need to highlight the highest value in the column group, which is the sum of all counts for that category in a given month.

Can't for the life of me figure it out, so if anyone could help that would be great!

Thanks

[Example of dataset](https://i.stack.imgur.com/axyRA.png)

[This is what I'm aiming for](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eoEwU.png)

[Table in Design View](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dvDOE.png)

[Current outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eNfKw.png)

Comment: you probably need to edit you question to show exactly what you expect to see with some sample data. I think I understand what you want but it's better to be very clear. Also show what you have tried so far

Comment: @AlanSchofield thanks - I've added a picture of what I'm aiming for. Unforuntately my remote desktop crashed and I lost what I'd tried so far :(

Comment: @AlanSchofield Thank you for your help.
The data is unfortunately slightly more complicated than your assumption, in that the categories are broken down into multiple sectors, and the value that I need to come out from the aggregation you've suggested would be the sum of the values from all sectors in the category for a given month.
Is that possible? I'll try and attach an example of the data to the question above.

Comment: that's what it will do, it will give you the sum of the entire category, so if I understood correctly it will work as expected.

Comment: @AlanSchofield - unfortunately not - it is giving me the value for the sector with the highest count, rather than for the sum of all sectors. I'll attach another picture above which will hopefully explain better than I can (Current outcome).
Thanks again for your help!

Comment: It looks like you have included Sector in the group by clause of the inner query. Based on your sample output you should ignore the sector column altogether. If this still does not help, can you post a SQL Fiddle (http://sqlfiddle.com) that recreates your sample data and then I can work with that.

Comment: I've recreated the dataset and tested it. It does what I expected. Check out the fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d20ab3/1

Comment: @AlanSchofield no one on SO is going to click on your links. Much better to embed images in your SO post itself.

Comment: @SherwinZadeh SQL Fiddle is commonly used to demonstrate working SQL code, you will find hundreds of examples on SO. And the point of it is that images of data are are useless to recreate scenarios. Please don't bother commenting is you have nothing useful to add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you will face is that you will have to try to use nested aggregates with scopes defined. This might be possible (but I don't think it is...)

There is a fairly simple way to fix it though. I can;t give an exact answer as I don;t know what your dataset looks like but typically you would have to make some changes to your dataset, then its simple.

So assuming your dataset looks something like this

```
Cat    myDate    counts
A      20171001  90
A      20171001  6
B      20171001  18
C      20171001  1
A      20171101  100
A      20171101  20
....
....
```

Then aggregate everything so the report does not have to do any real aggregation with something like

```
SELECT 
*
, max(counts) OVER(PARTITION BY Cat) as maxInCat
FROM (
        SELECT 
            Cat, myDate
            , SUM(counts) as counts
        FROM myTable 
        GROUP BY Cat, myDate
    ) x
```

This will give you a dataset with an additional column `maxInCat`. This column will contain the maximum value in each category so we can compare against this in the report.

The expression can then be something like

```
=IIF(SUM(Fields!counts.Value)>0 and SUM(Fields!counts.Value) = Fields!maxInCat.Value, "Yellow", Nothing)
```

**EDIT**

I've updated the actual backcolor expression as it didn't account for blanks/zeros

Ignoring the fact the the columns are not sorted as I don't have time, here's the result

[image]

Comment: I've recreated the dataset and tested it. It does what I expected. Check out the fiddle here http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/d20ab3/1

Answer (score 0):

Here's an answer that I think does what you need:

```
declare @Table as table
(
    [Cat] char(1),
    [Sector] tinyint,
    [Counts] int,
    [Date] date
);
insert into @Table
(
    [Cat],
    [Sector],
    [Counts],
    [Date]
)
values
('A', 1, 4103, '2017-10-01'), 
('A', 1, 3001, '2017-11-01'),
('A', 1, 1128, '2017-12-01'),
('A', 1, 5917, '2018-01-01'),
('A', 1, 9594, '2018-02-01'),
...
```

So you know where the data is coming from.

```
with [AggregatedData] as
(
    select 
        t.Cat,
        t.Sector,
        t.Counts,
        t.[Date],
        sum(t.Counts) over (partition by t.Cat, t.[Date]) as [SumCounts]
    from @Table as [t]
)
select 
    ad.Cat,
    ad.Sector,
    ad.Counts,
    ad.[Date],
    ad.SumCounts,
    max(ad.SumCounts) over (partition by ad.[Date]) as [MaxSumCounts]
from [AggregatedData] as [ad]
```

Then in SSRS, you can use:

```
=iif(IsNothing(Fields!SumCounts.Value) = FALSE AndAlso Fields!SumCounts.Value = Fields!MaxSumCounts.Value, "Yellow", "Transparent")
```

Which gives:
[image: Output]